# HTTPS url in UIWebview is not working in iphone / ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview, https

Im new to iphone development . trying to make sample browser application where i have used HTTPS url in UIWebview is not working in iphone / ipad.(https.example.com).

when im tried in safari i gave me the following error message :

""CAN NOT VERIFY SERVER IDENTITY - SAFARI CANT VERIFY THE IDENTITY WOULD YOU LIKE TO CONTINUE ANY WAY"".. when i pressed continue.it was working

but in my browser app its not working can any one help me in this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you need to download the web page manually and use `loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:` - there's no way to adjust the trust settings of a UIWebView's internal requests.

I'm not sure how this will work for any https resources (images, css, etc) on the same domain though. Hopefully it will work fine.

Comment: I think this issue is from website side, because if I open the same HTTPS URL in iPad's safari browser, it gives the same warning as in `UIWebView` but with different message and the same meaning. In my case, I cannot implement your solutions as I have CSS in my web page. Did any body find solution for this?